# Iptables GEOIP not working under Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, iptables

I've just installed xtables-*, compiled the geoip database, but when I try to use an iptables command it always gives back the following error:

#### Command

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m geoip --src-cc 'DE' -j DROP
```

#### Error

```
Could not open /usr/share/xt_geoip/LE/DE.iv0: No such file or directory
iptables v1.4.8: Could not read geoip database`
```

The problem is, that the support scripts create the geoip database, but they all end as `iv4` and `iv6`, not `iv0`. When I rename the `DE.iv4` file to `DE.iv0`, the error becomes:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

How can I breathe life into the system?

Comment: I have followed step by step in this tutorial, everything is describe, how to install and use iptables with geoip to block countries.
http://terminal28.com/how-to-block-countries-using-iptables-debian/

Answer (score 1):

The version of `xtables` in Debian Squeeze was pretty old, and it pre-dated the splitting of IPv4 and IPv6 into separate maps. This split happened 2010-12-18. [See here.](https://sourceforge.net/p/xtables-addons/xtables-addons/ci/25bf680ead80e505d5073308f151b4007cb5683f/)

Your support scripts are creating new-style `*.iv4` and `*.iv6` files, while the iptables extension module expects old-style `*.iv0` files.

If you're still using Squeeze, you'll need to find and download an *old* version of the support scripts used to create the IP maps. A suitable version might actually be included in the `xtables` source code package version that matches the binary package you may be currently using.

Answer (score -3):

Do no use 'DE' .. just write DE,CA,UK, like this, without quotes

Comment: You might want to provide an exact working command line.

Comment: I don't think quotes make differences , `'DE'` is same as `DE` here under bourne shell